# Understanding rounding with pow / base 10

Tags: php, rounding, pow

There is this function that is used tat I didn't myself create, but at the moment it is only returning the number rounded with `2 decimal places`, but I want to change it so it returns it with three; however I don't really understand how it all works.

Here is the function:

```
function round_number($number, $round = 2)
{
    // we will multiply by 10^$round, then get the floor value of that amount then divide by 10^round.
    ## -> if it does problems, switch back to floor()
    $temp_value = $number * pow(10, $round);
    $temp_value = (!strpos($temp_value, '.')) ? $temp_value : floor($temp_value);
    $number = $temp_value / pow(10, $round);

    return $number;
}
```

I assume if I change the `$round` to `3` that it will return correctly?

Comment: Have you tested your assumption?

Comment: try changing $round to 3 or calling the function like `round_number($nuber,3);`  or even better stop using it as you don't need it you can just use `round(), floor(), ceil(), number_format()`

Comment: @KaarelNummert Of course. But that doesn't necessarily mean it's the right method; I just want to make sure it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I questioned the use of it; not sure why they would need such a complex function when they could just use one of the aforementioned.

Comment: You'd only need a function like that if handling any other base apart from 10! so this is mostly just a waste of time function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 // we will multiply by 10^$round, then get the floor value of that amount then divide by 10^round.
## -> if it does problems, switch back to floor()
```

It says it right in the code what it does!

And yes - changing `$round = 3;` will work.

However DON'T you should instead just call the function

round_number(12345.12342423, 3);

the number passed in as second parameter `(3)` will override the `$round=2` in the function (`$round=2` is the 'default')

Comment: Yes I know the 2 will get overridden...... though reason I asked is cause we probably want to change it globally anyway. I know it says in the code, but I've never really been taught about to the power of math.

Comment: Power(10,3) = 10 * 10 * 10, pow(10,5) = 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 -> it is just how many time you times it by itself. I would suggest reading up on how to round in math if you want to understand the function in its entirety, if not then just either change the default to 3 or pass 3 in when calling it!!!